# Why MA model order is from acf but not pacf

Tags: arima, acf-pacf

For MA model in Arima, why the order references acf, but not pacf? The emphasize is why not PACF.

In https://towardsdatascience.com/significance-of-acf-and-pacf-plots-in-time-series-analysis-2fa11a5d10a8

It mentions

> Why would that be? Since our series is linear combination of the
>   residuals and none of time series own lag can directly explain its
>   present (since its not an AR), which is the essence of PACF plot as it
>   subtracts variations already explained by earlier lags, its kind of
>   PACF losing its power here

I don't still get why PACF cannot be used here, anyone can give a better intuition why it should be ACF but not PACF for giving the order for MA model?

Answer (score 1):

They are saying that an AR is something like $y_{t}=y_{t-1}b+e_{t}$ so that each $y_{t-1}$ has an influence on $y_{t}$. Therefore, it make sense to look at the corr between $y_{t-2}$ and $y_{t}$ which is not explained by $y_{t-1}$. In a MA instead you never have $y_{t-1}$ in the independent variables (right hand side). In other words, you can think also about the following: one of the most likely use of the PACF is that it helps you identify the order of a model (like the q in an AR(q)). But for a MA(q) the ACF goes to 0 after q lags, so you immediately see that:

- the process is not autoregressive otherwise you would have exponential decay,
- and you immediately get an intuition of the order.

So why drawing a PACF?

To answer your comment: ACF instead captures MA because MA(1) for example is $y_{t}=e_{t-1}b+e_{t}$ so $cov(y_{t}, y_{t-1})= cov(e_{t-1}, be_{t-1})=bVar(e_{t-1})$ so it will be non-zero up to lag 1, for lag 2 then ACF decays to 0 as you have no common white noise terms.

Comment: Thanks, now I see why PACF does not captures MA (as we don't have  $y_{t-1}$ in the right hand side variable - as you mentioned), but why ACF captures MA?

Comment: @william007 edited the question to answer your last comment

Comment: Thanks, it is getting clearer now, but $cov(y_{t}, y_{t-1})= cov(e_{t-1}, be_{t-1})=bVar(e_{t-1})$ this formula I can't see immediately how to establish it, is there any reference for it?

Comment: Try to search “ACF for MA process” and you should find plenty of things including the full explantation of the latter